# My Prop Tokens are lost in space

Tags: transactions

I sent all my props tokens to myself using a code .. only to see that the receiving account did not accept PROP tokens so now they are just sitting here at this address .. how do i get my funds back in my possession.  How do I access them!? Anyone please help

address of my funds https://etherscan.io/address/0xe0dddf05823c2ca5f459743052402fe9c44ff4b8

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it. Only the owner of the private key that generates that address can move the tokens. If the address belong to an exchange only them have access.